# Could not download backport-util-concurrent.jar (backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[Could not download backport-util-concurrent.jar (backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1): No cached version available for offline mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSzEj.png)

[image: gradle settings of AS]

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: please provide all text info in text format at the question :)

Comment: I am sure internet is connected

Answer (score 0):

You need an internet connection to download.
Make sure you are connected to the internet & Android Studio is not in offline mode.

To turn off offline mode in Android Studio:

- Click File > Settings (on macOS, Android Studio > Preferences) to
  open the Settings dialog.
- In the left pane, expand Build, Execution, Deployment and then click
  Gradle.
- Under Global Gradle settings, **uncheck** the Offline work checkbox.

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but there is still a  problem.My AS without that checkbox as you describe.By the way ,the vesion of AS is Android Studio 4.0